# Angular.JS - not filtering correctly/over filtering - syntax: filter:VAR:true?

Tags: javascript, java, json, angularjs, playframework

I am working with the Play Framework: https://github.com/lashford/modern-web-template/blob/master/public/partials/view.html

```
    <div class="form-group">           
        <input class="form-control" type="text" ng-model="searchText" placeholder="Type here to filter Users...">
        </div>
     <div class="form-group">
        <input class="form-control" type="text" ng-model="findAge" placeholder="Age Selector (SPECIFIC age filter)">
        </div>
            <hr>
        <table id="user_list" class="table table-striped">
            <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>FirstName</th>
                <th>LastName</th>
                <th>Age</th>
            </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            <tr ng-repeat="usr in uc.users | filter:searchText | filter:findAge:true">
                <td>
                    {{ usr.firstName }}
                </td>
                <td>
                    {{ usr.lastName }}
                </td>
                <td>
                    {{ usr.age }}
                </td>
                <td>
                    <a ng-href="/#/users/delete/{{usr.firstName}}/{{usr.lastName}}" class="btn btn-success pull-right" id="btn_user_update">Delete User</a>
                    <a ng-href="/#/users/edit/{{usr.firstName}}/{{usr.lastName}}" class="btn btn-success pull-right" id="btn_user_update">Edit User</a>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr ng-hide="uc.users.length">
                <td colspan="3">
                    <p class="text-center">No Users Found</p>
                </td>
            </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
```

I implemented filter:findAge:true to make sure filters were exact. In other words, if age is 27, I want 2 to filter it out since it isn't exactly the same as input.

Does anyone know why my findAge input field filters everything? The intended functionality: if I type 1 and age is 1 for one of the stored jsons, it should stay present. Instead, it filters.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the input type for `findAge` to number instead of text:

```
<input class="form-control" type="number" ng-model="findAge" placeholder="Age Selector (SPECIFIC age filter)">
```

Right now it's trying to match a string value with a stored number, which doesn't match using strict matching.

Plunkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/ZPKgHJrzRZYFCkM6A5Js?p=preview

Comment: Thanks! Exactly what I was looking for!